# Autonomous spending

Tags: gdp, consumption

"The term $\left(c_{0}+IQ+G-c_{1}T\right)$ is that part of the demand for goods that does not depend on output here ($c_{1}$ is mpc)."
Can someone please explain how will you interpret government spending (mpc $\times$ taxes). What does actually this part of the equation tell?

Comment: Not all of us are familiar with the terms used. Can you please be more specific about what $c_0$, $I$, $Q$, etc. are?

Comment: I think you forgot to add the relevant equation that you are referring to.